# visual studio: How to Read Settings in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I right-clicked the project name and added new item called "Application settings". At beginning, its name is "Settings1.settings", I changed to Settings.settings. 
Below is the screenshot:
[image]

I tried to read the settings in my form. But there is an error.
[image]

My questions:
1, Why I can not read the values in Settings.settings by "My.Settings.test"?

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, visual basic should have already created a settings file which should be located at My Project > Properties > Settings

Unless you need more settings files, there shouldn't be any need to create any settings files manually.

To answer the question at the bottom: I believe you would have to reference your settings in your class, and you wouldn't call these settings with My.Settings but rather with Settings.Test or Settings.Settings.Test - it's one of those two.

This is based on as far as I remember, I may be incorrect though.

Comment: Thanks, I found that the existing Settings (right-clicked my project, properties, -> settings).  Then, I created the test variable in this settings file. Now, I can use My.Settings.test to read this stored value.

Comment: @BAE No worries, glad my answer helped!